# What is the difference between Vss and Vs in a transistor?

Tags: amplifier

I know the difference between Vdd and Vcc and all the other ones, but I can't figure this out. What's the difference between Vss and Vs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- V<sub>S</sub> is the voltage of a transistor's source terminal. It usually refers to a (MOS)FET transistor.
- V<sub>SS</sub> is the voltage rail *beyond* the transistor's source terminal. It refers to power rails, usually the negative one.

Comment: Not a big deal by why SS? Does the extra S stand for something?

Comment: @Andyaka The S to my knowledge isn't an abbreviation for something. The second S (or C in V<sub>CC</sub> or E in V<sub>EE</sub> ...) means something like "beyond".

Comment: OK dude, interesting all the same. Never gave it much thought before!

Comment: I think it is just a means to indicate plural, i.e. many source terminals are connected to Vss.

Answer (score 2):

Going back a ways, Vs refers to any (V)oltage (s)ource. For early logic ICs, which could use odd supply voltages, Vss stood for "substrate voltage". Sometimes this meant ground, sometimes not. See, as an example, http://www.datasheetarchive.com/dl/Scans-022/ScansEX55919.pdf which is a the digital logic for a 4 1/2 digit A/D converter for making DPMs. It has two power pins, Vss and Vdd. Vss is set to +5, and Vdd to (typically) -15. Note that that there is no ground pin.